# How can I Autowire an entity from external Jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm new to spring boot, and I have spent some hours trying to figure out why when I move my entity to another project I'm getting an error: "java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type net.learn.spring.entity.Book not present". What I'm missing?

This is my project structure:

[image]

This is my entity project structure:

[image]

Entity project POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.mystest</groupId>
    <artifactId>CommonVO</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name> </name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my StartApplication class:

```
package net.learn.spring;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import net.learn.spring.entity.Book;
import net.learn.spring.repository.Repository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication spa = new SpringApplication(StartApplication.class);
        spa.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.save(new Book("Las 1000 y una noches"));
        
    }

}
package net.learn.spring.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import net.learn.spring.entity.Book;

public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Book,Integer>{

}
package net.learn.spring.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ta_book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Book [id=");
        builder.append(id);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    
}
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.learn</groupId>
  <artifactId>LearningSpringBoot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonVO</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

console output

[image]

Comment: That other project is that a spring boot project as well or a regular project. Or to put it in other words does the other project use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as well?

Comment: @m-deinum not really, its just a maven project.

Comment: As mentioned, please add the `pom.xml` and also is this a multi-module project, just a seperate project?

Comment: @m-deinum I have already aded entity project pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post pom.xml file of the CommonVO project?
Also, I advise you to add EntityScan annotation to your StartApplication like this:
@EntityScan("net.learn.spring.entity.*")

It is used to identify the base package where entities are scanned during application startup.

Answer (score 1):

Update your main class like below:

```java
...
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "net.learn.spring.entity")
public class StartApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
...
```

`@EntityScan` tells Spring where you keep your `@Entity` files (which will be used by the persistence context). Since your main class and Entity classes lie in different packages, Spring can not find your entities by default and needs you to show the location for them.

Comment: Whats the difference between @EntityScan(basePackages = "net.learn.spring.entity") and @EntityScan("net.learn.spring.entity")

Comment: @Jose there's [no difference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.java#L65)

Answer (score 0):

You have to scan the package that contains the entity class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.package.external.class")
class Config {
...
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. An Entity is not a a component. Maybe @EntityScan might work though?